# Django forget password in login page

Tags: django

We know in the Django login admin page you can just enter user/pass and log in to the admin panel.

But is there any method to add the forget password option to this page? Or there is any package for it?

Comment: you need to write a basic view and inherit django login page and do your task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django docs describes this here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-a-password-reset-feature

And it provides default templates for that so there is minimal work required.

```
/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_change_form.html
```

Remember that to send emails with reset link you need to configure Email Backend first